# How to get Deleted Row Count in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I´m making a DELETE FROM in HQL:

```
String queryText = DELETE FROM Books WHERE author = 'author1'

final Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryText);

query.executeUpdate();
```

How can I get the number of deleted rows in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `executeUpdate` return the number of entities deleted.

So you will get the number of deleted rows (`n`) by the following code :

```
 int n = query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The **preparedStatement.executeUpdate()** returns the number of rows affected.

For ex:

```
int row =preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```